# Plug-in dependencies conflict in a windows process

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I'm creating plug-in for a main windows process. Those plug-ins are assemblies (dll) which shared the same dependent assemblies but using different version as both plug-ins were not released in the same point in time (see below two assemblies in different version if we use the modules window of Visual Studio).

If only one plugin is loaded, everything works fine, indeed, if both plug-ins get loaded in the process, then, potential error can occur as one plug-in might use the wrong version. I thought initially that putting the assembly in the GAC and fixing the version in the csproj (or directory.build.props) would help but apparently, this fix version is only used at designed time. I try to add a config file with a binding redirect but it seems once the two assemblies are loaded in the process, there is no way to force usage of a particular version. Is there any smart way to avoid this conflict so the entry point dll use always the correct version of the assembly despite having two versions available in the process?

[image]